# How does memory_limit work in PHP?

Tags: php

If I have two scripts and my `memory_limit` option is set to **64M** (for example). If I run script 1 and it takes **40M** and simultaneously run script 2 how much memory does it have free?

Does every script has up to **64M** or they share this memory?

Comment: `memory_limit` is the max amount of memory each script may allocate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Each** PHP script running independently is subject to its own memory limit ([as set by the configuration option *memory_limit*](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)). This limit is inherited into all included scripts (as those are dependent on the parent script).

**An example - two scripts running in parallel:**

- you open a webpage `/script1.php`
- you also open a webpage `/script2.php`

As these two are completely independent (there is no simple way to discover that "the other script" is running, or even that it exists), they will get a 64M limit *each* - so the amount of memory they are allowed to use is 64M for one, which comes out to 128M for two. (To clarify, it is not possible to "share" this memory between scripts: if script1.php only consumes 1MB, it can not "give" the rest of its limit to script2.php)

**A different scenario - one script including another script:**

- you open a webpage `/script1.php`

  - that script has a line `require('script2.php')`

In this case, there is only a single 64MB limit: this is still considered a single script, no matter how many files it include()s or require()s. In other words, `script2.php` inherits the limit (as well as the other PHP settings) from `script1.php` and all the memory used here is counted towards that limit.

Note that it is possible to change this limit *from inside the script* (if your server's configuration allows this - most do). Using `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');` sets the new limit to 128 MB - but all the memory used by the script so far still counts towards this limit.

**Scripts including other scripts and dynamically changing the memory limit:**

- you open the webpage `/script1.php` (in script1.php, limit 64 MB set from configuration)

  - that runs `require('script2.php')` (in script1.php, limit 64 MB inherited)

    - that runs `ini_set('memory_limit','200MB')` (in script2.php, changed explicitly to 200 MB)
    - that runs `require('script3.php')` (in script2.php, limit 200 MB as set above)

      - that runs `require('script4.php')` (in script3.php, limit 200 MB inherited)

        - that runs `ini_set('memory_limit','-1')` (in script4.php, changed explicitly to "no limit")
        - that runs `require('script5.php')` (in script4.php, "no limit on memory" inherited)

---

Note: It is possible to set a *lower* limit than it is currently, but this risks immediately overrunning it ("we're using 80 MB" - "set limit to 64 MB" - "out of memory error"); because of this risk, this is rarely attempted.

Note also that `memory_limit` is a configuration setting and as such it can be set [in various places](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php); or its modification can be [prevented](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) by the system administrator.

Comment: Hi

I would like to ask you a question about how it works.

I hae a framework that customly developed by our team. And we're using it in a site with 256MB memory_limit

Our server has 24 gb RAM so is this means that our server can handle approximately 256 * 4 * 24 simultaneous connection?

I mean is this limit applies on per visitor to site or how apache can calculate this limit?

Comment: The limit applies per running PHP script (e.g. if the visitor has five pages loading at the moment, the maximum usage of that visitor at the moment is 5*256): if the script tries to allocate more memory, it will fail - but the server won't allocate the memory unless the script actually needs it. Note that there are other things running on the server besides PHP, so you don't have the full 24 GB for yourself. Also, this is the *maximum* the script can get - most scripts request much less than the maximum.

Answer (score 4):

From the PHP Manual:

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is
>   allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for
>   eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no
>   memory limit, set this directive to -1.

Meaning each script gets the same 64M amount of memory.